# Spring Data returns different UUID for objects in objects each time I call a GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

**Background**

I have a person in a spring data neo4j database.
I this database every person has a pet.
The pet has a UUID (as do people).

When I run a GET on all people (api/v1/person) it loads something like this:

```
...
  {
    "@id": 53,
    "uuid": "0a546f49-760e-4c3e-b725-77aa3052c803",
    "name": "John",
    "description": "A good guy",
    "pet": {
      "property_type": "Object",
      "@id": 54,
      "uuid": "8ea113d5-b7ff-4ddc-88fb-31ada32e3b5f",
      "name": " Default",
      "description": "",
      "properties": []
    },
    "items": [],
  },
 ...
```

Then I run a GET on the single person shown above (api/v1/person/0a546f49-760e-4c3e-b725-77aa3052c803) and I get:

```
  {
    "@id": 53,
    "uuid": "0a546f49-760e-4c3e-b725-77aa3052c803",
    "name": "John",
    "description": "A good guy",
    "pet": {
      "property_type": "Object",
      "@id": 54,
      "uuid": "c35dff3d-f7dd-460c-a69d-1c7fa734594f",
      "name": " Default",
      "description": "",
      "properties": []
    },
    "items": [
     {
       "name":"sword of gondor",
       "type":"melee"
     }
    ],
  },
```

Notice how the depth of the GET has increased, but also the uuid of pet is now different. If I run this last GET again it always gives the same UUID for pet. But, the GET on all persons keeps changing the UUID for pet for John.

**Question**

How/Why does the UUID keep changing for pets on GETs that get all people.

**Notes**

I am using swagger to make the GET calls and both seem to be built in CRUD calls on the spring data neo4j framework.

**Some Code if it helps**

```
@Api(tags = "Person", description = "Person Management API")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/person")
public class PersonController extends Controller<Person>{

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    @Override
    public Service<Person> getService() {
        return personService;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

A person extends (eventually) to this class with this code:

```
...
public abstract class EntityWithPet extends NamedEntity {

    @Relationship(direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    protected ObjectSchema objectSchema = new ObjectSchema();

    /**
     * 
     */
    public EntityWithPet() {
        super();
        setName(getName());
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     * @param description
     */
    public EntityWithPet(String name, String description) {
        super(name, description);
        setName(name);
    }
...
```

Comment: I would assume that for each GET request a different class is used as a response object. How is the GET method that handles the `person/{uuid}` request implemented?

Comment: @LazerBass I believe that all the CRUD are built into the @ RestController annotation.